# Node .getTextContent() removing child tags and concatenating its content

Tags: java, csv, aiml

I have a AIML file just like this:

```
<xml>
<aiml>
<category>
<pattern>Question 1</pattern>
<that>Optional</that>
<template>Answer</template>
</category>
<category>
<pattern>Question 2</pattern>
<that>Optional</that>
<template><random><li>Answer 1</li><li>Answer 2</li></random></template>
</category>
<topic name="test">
<category>
<pattern>Question 1</pattern>
<that>Optional</that>
<template><random><li>Answer 1</li><li>Answer 2</li><li>Answer 3</li></random></template>
</category>
</topic>
</aiml>
```

And I want to convert it into CSV:

```
0,Question 1,*,Optional, Answer,test.aiml
0,Question 2,*,Optional, <random><li>Answer 1</li><li>Answer 2</li></random>,test.aiml
0,Question 1,test,*, <random><li>Answer 1</li><li>Answer 2</li><li>Answer 3</li></random>,test.aiml
```

But the result is:

```
0,Question 1,*,Optional, Answer,test.aiml
0,Question 2,*,Optional, Answer 1Answer 2,test.aiml
0,Question 1,test,*, Answer 1Answer 2Answer 3,test.aiml
```

I don't know why but node.getTextContent() removes all tags and return only its content.
toString returns the tag name.
And I can't find a method to process random and li tags as text.
Thats how I get the tag content:

```
eElement.getElementsByTagName("template").item(0).getTextContent();
```

Comment: that's how getTextContent works. if you want to preserve html tags you can use getInnerHtml

Comment: See [the method documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent--) and the [definition of "content" in the XML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-content).